# How to create an annotation to prevent some values?

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create an annotation in java to prevent some values inserted in a method? For example:

```
public void getInfo(@AnnotationName int position){
}
```

So, in the end, the "position" will get a value between e.x 40 - 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation is a declaration only. It is not a eventuality that annotations are declared using keyword `@interface`.

You can define a rule using annotation. However somebody must implement code and this code must be executed.

So, you have several solutions.

(1) You can implement all this yourself without annotations at all:

```
public void getInfo(int position){
    if(postion < 40  || position > 50) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong position")l
    }
}
```

Ugly, but works.

(2) If for example you have interface and its several implementations you can use Wrapper (or Decorator) pattern and implement your own wrapper that performs validations only:

```
public interface InformationProvider {
    public void getInfo(int position);
}

public class InformationProviderImpl implements InformationProvider {
    public void getInfo(int position) {
         // your implementation
    }
}



public class InformationProviderValidator implements InformationProvider {
    private final InformationProvider provider;
    private final int min;
    private final int max;
    public InformationProviderValidator(InformationProvider provider, int min, int max) {
        this.provider = provider;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
    public void getInfo(int position) {
        if(postion < min  || position > max) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong position")l
        }
        return provider.getInfo(position);
    }
}
```

(3) Method #2 can be improved. You can indeed define annotation, e.g.

```
public @interface Min {
    int value();
}
public @interface Max {
    int value();
}
```

Now `InformationProviderValidator` can discover class of provider `provider` and extract min and max values from annotations.

(4) It is just 1 step from this solution to aspect-oriented programming. You can use AspectJ, for example.

(5) Similar solution is to use validation framework. Java defines standard annotations (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html). (JSR 303). As far as I know there are 2 implementation of this standard: 
  - http://bval.apache.org/
  - http://hibernate.org/validator/

Answer (score 1):

There are two general ways to prevent a method from executing with certain formal parameter values.

- Do run-time checking.  At run time, when the method is called, some code runs and throws an exception if the argument values are illegal.  This does not prevent the illegal call, and your code will crash at run time, but it does prevent the method from executing when called with the illegal arguments.  You can implement this using assertions, by throwing an exception explicitly, via [bean validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html), etc.
- Do compile-time checking.  At compile time, the compiler issues a warning if the method is called with values that may be illegal.  This does prevent the illegal call, and there is no need for run-time checking nor possibility of a run-time crash.  To implement this, you need to create an [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) that runs as a plug-in to javac.
  Frameworks exist to make it easy to create a compile-time annotation processor that ensures that methods are called legally.  One example is the [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/).

Comment: Yes, Checker Framework seems like a perfect match if the compiler has access to all possible usages of the method, but it won't help if the class is exported as a library (in which case bean validation is probably the way to go)

Answer (score -1):

Try bean validation: http://beanvalidation.org/
There are many annotations that help validating the input into your beans

Comment: I see..so is there a guide or a tutorial for that?